# Identical controller and library class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it wrong to have two similar class name (one in lib and one in controller)?

#### myapp/lib/company/api.rb

```
module Company
  class Api
    include HTTParty

    base_uri "#{API_CONFIG['scheme']}://#{API_CONFIG['host']}"
    digest_auth API_CONFIG['email'], API_CONFIG['key']

    DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
      limit: 1
    }

  #...
end
```

### myapp/app/controllers/api/something_controller.rb

```
class Api::SomethingController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # TODO: Verify q
    q = params[:q]

    @result = Company::Api.new().send("get_sdf_#{q}",
                                   rn: "123",
                                   limit: params[:limit])


  #...
end
```

### development.log

```
LoadError (Expected /home/cekpo/myapp/lib/company/api.rb to define Api):
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:503:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:554:in `get'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have two identical named classes here. One class is named `Api`, defined in module `Company`. The other one is class `SomethingController` defined within module `Api`.

I think you forgot to define module `Company`.

Add a file named `lib/Company.rb` with contents

```
module Company
end
```

Now it should work.